# TypeError: is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm just using the code as a learning exercise regarding JavaScript classes.

The code produces a "TypeError: SimpleLogger is not a constructor". The class seems to be exported Ok but I can't instantiate it in the main.js file.

I've reduced the code to just show the issue. I was wondering if anyone can spot the problem. Thanks.

```
// In simplelogger.js
"use strict";
class SimpleLogger {
    constructor(level) {
        this.level = level || DEFAULT_LEVEL;
    }

    // .... other methods
}

const DEFAULT_LEVEL = 'info';

module.exports = {
    SimpleLogger,
    DEFAULT_LEVEL
}

// In main.js
"use strict";
const SimpleLogger = require('./simplelogger.js');

let log = new SimpleLogger('info');
```

The error is produced in the last line.

Comment: You don't need `use strict`.

Comment: You're exporting an object with two keys (SimpleLogger and DEFAULT_LEVEL); Maybe the constant of log level can belong to SimpleLogger and exporting the class with default.

Comment: @Geuis What's wrong with using `"use strict"`? It's generally good practice to include this in your code, as long as it doesn't run at top-level.

Comment: @kevinji Actually you're probably right. I have been working exclusively with es6+ for the last few years where strict mode at the module level is enabled and part of the spec. So there's no need for it there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417381/how-is-the-use-strict-statement-interpreted-in-node-js

Comment: I've seen 'use strict' just after the class definition rather than at the top of the module. Is there a preference in placement or should I not use it at all?

Comment: @RedSandman If you're in an environment that supports ES6 modules natively, then top of the module is fine. In browsers, I believe `"use strict"` only applies per `<script>` tag, so including it in any of your code should be fine. See also: [Would this enable “use strict” globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483768/would-this-enable-use-strict-globally)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're exporting an object containing both `SimpleLogger` and `DEFAULT_LEVEL` therefore to use it in main.js you need to reference it properly like so

```
const SimpleLogger = require('./simplelogger.js').SimpleLogger;
let log = new SimpleLogger('info');
```

If you only want to export `SimpleLogger` you can change your export like so

```
module.exports = SimpleLogger
```

Then you can require `SimpleLogger` as you do in your code.

Comment: That's fixed it. Thank you.