# Using Turndown in Vue - TypeError: TurndownService is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to convert HTML to Markdown in a Vue-application.

I'm trying to implement Turndown, but I'm getting the error, in the console:

```
TypeError: TurndownService is not a constructor
```

I'm using Webpack, to compile it. This is the vue-component I'm trying to use it in:

```
<script>
  var TurndownService = require('turndown');
  console.log( new TurndownService() ); // Returns 'undefined';
  export default {
    mounted() {
      var turndownService = new TurndownService();
      this.markdownContent = turndownService.turndown( 
        '<a href="https://example.org">A link</a><p>Hello world</p>' 
      );
    },
    ...
    ...
```

This is what it looks like in node_modules:

[image: turndown folder structure]

---

I've tried all kind of things, to solve it. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318369/typeerror-is-not-a-constructor), I tried

```
var TurndownService = require('turndown').TurndownService;
```

and

```
var TurndownService = require('turndown/dist/turndown').TurndownService;
```

... But no cigar. :-/

Answer (score 9):

Found your post while dealing with the same.

This fixed it for me:

```
const TurndownService = require('turndown').default;
```

After that, the regular instructions worked like a charm!